# XeLaTeX + unicode-math enters infinite loop if \nin is defined?

Tags: xetex, amsmath, unicode-math, amsart

I frequently use the abbreviation \nin with the definition

```
\newcommand{\nin}{\not\in}
```

However, when I started doing this using xelatex and unicode-math it causes xelatex to stall.  In particular the following document seems to put xelatex into an infinite loop

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newcommand{\nin}{\not\in}
\begin{document}
    \( a \nin b \)
\end{document}
```

Frankly I'm quite puzzled as my command is defined after all packages are loaded (still fails even if I define the command after begin document) and no existing command collides with it so what is going on?

Is there any way that I can make this macro work (ideally in a way that works in both xelatex+unicode-math and pdflatex)

Just to be clear it is the *definition* of \nin plus the use of \not\in that causes trouble as if I replace.

```
\( a \nin b \)
```

with

```
\( a \not\in b \)
```

it still stalls but if I instead replace it with

```
\( a \in b \)
```

it executes fine.

Pursuant to egreg's comment I can define \nin as \notin and everything compiles fine.  I would, however, still like to know what is going on here so I won't run into the same problem again.

Comment: `\not\in` has been wrong since day 1 and should be `\notin`.

Comment: egreg's observation that I should use \notin lets me define \nin as \notin and everything compiles.  However, I would still like to know why \not\in (which **works fine without the \nin macro**) causes a problem in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `\not` is defined in `unicode-math`:

```
\cs_new:Npn \__um_newnot:N #1
 {
   \tl_set:Nx \l_not_token_name_tl { \token_to_str:N #1 }
   \exp_args:Nx \tl_if_empty:nF { \tl_tail:V \l_not_token_name_tl }
    {
     \tl_set:Nx \l_not_token_name_tl { \tl_tail:V \l_not_token_name_tl }
    }
   \cs_if_exist:cTF { n \l_not_token_name_tl }
    {
     \use:c { n \l_not_token_name_tl }
    }
    {
     \cs_if_exist:cTF { not \l_not_token_name_tl }
      {
       \use:c { not \l_not_token_name_tl }
      }
      {
       \__um_oldnot: #1
      }
    }
 }
```

Here `\__um_oldnot:` is the legacy `\not`; at begin document, `\not` is set equal to `\__um_newnot:N`.

Essentially, when you do `\not\foo`, the macro checks whether `\nfoo` is defined (several negated symbols are named this way). Otherwise it checks for `\notfoo` and failing it uses the negation slash.

Do you see the problem? If `\nin` is defined as you do, it's executed, which restarts the cycle, because it does `\not\in`… Infinite loop.

Note that `\not\in` has been wrong since day 1 of TeX (and its standard fonts) and it should be `\notin`.

### Solution

```
\newcommand{\nin}{\notin}
```

### Comments

The underlying idea in `unicode-math` is to help users into getting the right symbols. Your case shows users neglect the recommendation to use `\notin` rather than `\notin`: can you spot the difference when using `pdflatex` and Computer Modern?

[image]

Similarly, it's frequent to find `\not\mid` instead of `\nmid`.

More importantly, if a negated symbol exists in the Unicode repertoire, it *should* be used independently from user’s input. So `\not\mid` *ought* to be translated internally into `\nmid` and, similarly, `\not\in` into `\notin` (that for `unicode-math` represents a single character, rather than a superposition of two glyphs like with the legacy fonts). If we look in `unicode-math-table.tex`, we find

```
\nexists
\notin
\nni
\nmid
\nparallel
\nsim
```

and several others. Possibly there should also be `\nin`, but the tradition is to call it `\notin`.

Note that if you define `\nfoo` to be `\not\foo`, you run into the same problem as with `\in`.

Comment: So in general I would run into problems if I tried to define a command \nTleq to be \not\Tleq.

But also if I define \nTleq to display in a nice fashion then (at least with unicode-math) I can count on \not\Tleq to automatically use this definition not simply put a slash through it?

Comment: @PeterGerdes If you define `\nTleq` to use `\not\Tleq`, you run in the same problem.