# (unicode-math or newtxmath) + \newcommand{\nmodels}{\not\models} + $\not\models$ = stall

Tags: macros, unicode-math, newtxmath

Feeding the input

```
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi
\fi
\documentclass{standalone}
\ifxetexorluatex
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\else
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\fi
\newcommand{\nmodels}{\not\models}%%% or \providecommand, or \providecommand* instead of \newcommand; the effect is the same.
\begin{document}
\(\nmodels\) %%% or \(\not\models\); the effect is the same.
\end{document}
```

to any of `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, or `lualatex` causes an infinite loop.  Well, in case of [XeLaTeX + unicode-math enters infinite loop if \nin is defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360950/xelatex-unicode-math-enters-infinite-loop-if-nin-is-defined)  you can use `\notin` instead of `\not\in`, but what do you do if you like the shape of `\models` (rather than that of `\vDash`), want a negated form of it, and want to call it `\nmodels`? The form of `\nvDash` is different, so, it's not advisable to use both `\models` and  `\nvDash` in the same document.  Using (the whole of) MnSymbols is out of question: it may still have bugs (I knew it had some 10 years ago and stopped using it then), changes quite a a few symbols, and clashes with NewTX fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current implementation of `\not` does essentially the same in `pdflatex` as in (Xe|Lua)LaTeX with `unicode-math`.

More precisely, `\not` takes the next token, say `\foo` and first checks whether `\notfoo` is defined; if the test succeeds, `\notfoo` is used. Otherwise the next check is whether `\nfoo` is defined. Again, if this test succeeds, `\nfoo` is used. Otherwise LaTeX does `\n@tch@r\foo`.

Now you see why an infinite loop is started: `\nmodels` does `\not\models`; since `\nmodels` is defined, it is used, which does `\not\models`…

You can avoid the issue by applying `\not` to `\relax` (hoping that neither `\notrelax` nor `\nrelax` are defined, which is unlikely).

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{iftex}
\iftutex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
\else
  \usepackage{newtxmath}
\fi

\newcommand{\nmodels}{\not\relax\models}%

\begin{document}

\(\nmodels\)

\(\not\models\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Anyway, this is not a particularly good way to negate `\models`. Compare with the following.

```latex
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{iftex}
\iftutex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
\else
  \usepackage{newtxmath}
\fi
\usepackage{centernot}

\newcommand{\nmodels}{\centernot\models}%

\begin{document}

\(\nmodels\)

\(\not\models\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It turned out that I don't include the `centernot` package but still have the `\centernot` command (with the intended semantics) due to one of the dozens of other packages I use.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `\not` is getting too clever by half by looking up whether `\nmodels` or `\notmodels` already exist.

It works if you change the name:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
\else
  \usepackage{newtxmath}
\fi

%\newcommand{\aintmodel}%
  %{\mathrel{\ooalign{\(\models\)\cr\hidewidth\(\mathslash\)\hidewidth}}}

\newcommand\aintmodel{\not\models}

\begin{document}
\( \aintmodel \)
\end{document}
```

This lookup gets performed whenever the symbol is used, and the definition of `\not` isn’t fully-expandable, so you can’t define the symbol with `\let` or `\edef` and sidestep this.

You could, however, create the symbol with `\ooalign` instead.  (Use `/` with `newtxmath` instead of `\mathslash`.)

Clearly, `unicode-math` now needs to search for the prefix `aint`.

### Update

You can also call `\not` without using the name `\models`, preventing the look-up.  For example,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{iftex}

\usepackage{unicode-math}


\newcommand\nmodels{\mathrel{\not\symbol{"22A7}}}

\begin{document}
\( \nmodels \)
\end{document}
```

Comment: "[...] want to call it `\nmodels` [...]"

Comment: @GeekestGeek Okay. I posted a solution different from egreg’s that lets you call it `\nmodels`. He’s got a good one too.